# Padding/width issue - Can I use box-sizing with a grid system e.g. 960 grid system?

Tags: css, width, padding, 960.gs, grid-system

I have been using the 960 grid system for a while and I always have the problem when adding padding to my divs.

I am wondering if it is a good/safe practice to modify the grid system CSS and add `box-sizing: border-box` to my *grid_x* classes. Are there any disadvantages?

So far I have been using an internal div with extra padding, so I don't mess with my divs containing the grid classes. It has worked fine but it just fills my layout with extra divs all over the place.

Is `box-sizing` a good option or do you have any other work-around, solutions, suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's the best if you add a box inside a grid_x, then add border for the box.

here is the example

html :

```
<div class="grid_1">
    <div class="box">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.grid_1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.box{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @yoel That'sm y previouse  approach, I was just thinking if box-sizing was a better/easier one.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking the same thing court. I know the HTML Bones wordpress theme uses box-sizing and it works great. It's not supported in IE7 and down, so you'll need to find a workaround. IE7 aside, I'd say the answer is yes.

edit: 
Found the IE7 workaround http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/
Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will definitely give it a try.